# Some npm packages in the ui5 project created by webide template can not be audited by npm

Tags: sapui5

The dev dependencies in package.json file

```
 "devDependencies": {
    "@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build": "1.4.2",
    "@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-test": "2.0.1"
 }
```

And I run npm audit for the project, npm told me there are 34 packages has audit problem.
I tried to fix it with `npm audit fix` but failed.
I checked the dependencies tree and make sure the problem packages are required by the above two packages.

So could you provide a way to fix the problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't audit `@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-build` and `@sap/grunt-sapui5-bestpractice-test` locally, because they are only available in the SAP WebIDE and not officially published on npm.

The are only use during build time, when deploying the app (hence "devDependencies").
They might be replaced by the [UI5 Tooling](https://github.com/SAP/ui5-tooling) in the future.